# Why do I need two return values within a function?

Tags: javascript, return

This question is very basic and very simple but I need to understand it.

I have this function in React:

```
renderPosts() {
  return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
        { post.title }
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

Why do I need the first return?

Basically, the second return will return me the li's. Why do I need to return (first return) them again? I need someone to help me explain this part. I am just confused.

Comment: The second `return` is part of the callback used by `map` - it is **not** the `return` for the `renderPosts` function

Comment: 2 different functions, 2 different returns

Comment: Two comments, two answers erroneously placed in the comments section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first return is going to return the result of `_.map()`, which returns individual posts.  The end result would be an array of posts as `<li/>` elements.

Comment: That is what I intuitively was thinking. But why doesn't the second return statement within the _.map function suffice? I mean it basically says:

For every post return me an li with the posts title.

Comment: @WalterMonecke because the result of `_.map` is local to the function if you don't `return` it

Comment: @UnholySheep so for clarification: The _.map function will return me something like this

    `<li> title blah <li>
     <li> title blaaah <li>`

And afterwards the first return is returning both these li's?

Comment: @WalterMonecke close, `_.map` returns an array, but otherwise yes, that's how it work

Comment: Sorry - had to dash out after I posted this answer.  Thanks for filling in @UnholySheep :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is because you are in javascript. So the first return, is the return of the function (the prototype map of your object "_" ). And the second return is the return of your map function.